# Congruent triangles that do not use reflections

Tags: geometry, reference-request, triangles, congruences-geometry

This is a simple question on terminology in geometry:

Suppose $ABC$ and $DEF$ are two triangles that are congruent, but the transformations from one to the other are based solely *only* on translation and rotation and *not* on reflections. Is there a name for this type of "super congruency"? Relatedly, is there a name when a reflection is needed?

I couldn't find anything on wikipedia or here about this - but this must have been named by some geometers. Any reference would be very welcome.

Comment: https://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/directly+congruent+figures

Comment: @Intelligentipauca Thanks - how would you call it if you have to use reflections? Indirectly congruent? Cheers.

Comment: Yes, I think so.